# How to query one random row, prioritizing last 6 hours?

Tags: php, mysql, random

I have a table called `adverts`, which I pull random records from

```
SELECT date, body FROM adverts ORDER BY rand()
```

Using the records `date` field, how can I prioritise only pulling random records added in the last 6 hours. I want to pull a single record

If there are no entries in the last six hours, then expand the search to 12, 18, so on

Any tidy way to do this? Using PHP and mySQL

Comment: How many rows do you need to return?

Comment: first start by sharing your `SHOW CREATE TABLE adverts` and some example data..

Comment: so if one record was found from the last 6 hours then you want nothing else and if nothing was found from the last 6 then you want all from last 12 even if it's 100 records?

Comment: I just want one record pulling at all times. If nothings been added in the last 6 hours, then expand the search to 12 hours. Using PHP and MySQL

Answer (score 0):

Without more information, assuming you are using `MySQL`, a great way to go is creating a `variable` that contains the minimum distance between now and your time variable,
and then, select all that corresponds to this time.

You can even select the variable to know how many hours have passed between the current time and your minimum time.

```
set @hours = (select min(hours) from (select TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, 
your_time_variable,
curdate()) as hours from adverts) t);


SELECT * FROM adverts
WHERE (TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, your_time_variable, curdate())) = @hours
ORDER BY rand();
```

You could customize these to filter what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it's worthwhile to do this in one query. The method of selecting random rows using `ORDER BY RAND()` is always pretty costly, so running it multiple times is not a good idea.

Here's another strategy: figure out the most recent window of time that does have data.

```
SELECT CEILING(TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, MAX(date), NOW()) / 6) * 6 FROM adverts;
```

For example I tested adding a row to a table using a timestamp 9 hours old. The query above returned 12.

```
mysql> SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, MAX(date), NOW()) FROM adverts;
+---------------------------------------+
| TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, MAX(date), NOW()) |
+---------------------------------------+
|                                     9 |
+---------------------------------------+

mysql> SELECT CEILING(TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, MAX(date), NOW())/6)*6 FROM adverts;
+----------------------------------------------------+
| CEILING(TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, MAX(date), NOW())/6)*6 |
+----------------------------------------------------+
|                                                 12 |
+----------------------------------------------------+
```

This way you can know the best length of time to use for your random selection query:

```
SELECT date, body FROM adverts WHERE date >= NOW() - INTERVAL 12 HOUR
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can write a stored procedure to handle the logic:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE fetchSample(
IN limit_size INT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE x  INT;
    DECLARE y  INT;

    SET x = 0;
    SET y = 0;

    WHILE x  <= 4 AND y = 0 DO

        SET  x = x + 1; 
        SET  y = (SELECT count(*) FROM adverts WHERE  yourDateTimeField BETWEEN 
        NOW() - INTERVAL CONVERT(6 * x, CHAR) HOUR AND NOW() ORDER BY rand()
        LIMIT limit_size);

    END WHILE;

    SELECT * FROM adverts WHERE  yourDateTimeField BETWEEN 
    NOW() - INTERVAL CONVERT(6 * x, CHAR) HOUR AND NOW() ORDER BY rand() 
    LIMIT limit_size;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but the OP didn't say they are using a programming langue (like Java or PHP). The OP probably wants 1 query to return the data they need.

Comment: @isaace I just updated my answer. He can do the logic with a stored procedure.